# CROSS APPLY a FREETEXTTABLE

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, freetexttable, cross-apply

MS SQL Server 2005: table1 has a full text index.  I want to run multiple freetexttable searches against it in a single query, but the two attempts i have fail.  any help would be appreciated, thanks!  p.s.  am willing to upgrade to sql 2008 if it fixes this :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnt_FullTextSearch ( @s NVARCHAR(4000) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
    ( SELECT [key], [rank]
        FROM FREETEXTTABLE(table1, *, @s) )

DECLARE @terms TABLE ( term VARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES ( 'flu' )
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES ( 'acid' )

-- The inline function "..." cannot 
-- take correlated parameters or subqueries 
-- because it uses a full-text operator.
SELECT ft.[key], ft.[rank]
    FROM @terms 
        CROSS APPLY fnt_FullTextSearch(term) ft

--syntax error on term
SELECT ft.[key], ft.[rank]
    FROM @terms 
        CROSS APPLY FREETEXTTABLE(table1, *, term)
```

Comment: @user433342 : Can you add the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you are missing the alias on the second statement ?

```
SELECT FT.[key], FT.[rank]
    FROM @terms 
        CROSS APPLY FREETEXTTABLE(table1, *, term) FT
```

It sounds trivial...but I dont see any other reason why it should fail !